# Any unix command to get the result of most-recently executed command?

Tags: unix

For example,

I executed "pwd" and it shows the current working directory. Then if I want to reuse that result in my another command, it would convenient to get it via a Unix command or built-in variable. Does it exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the result, as in return code, using `$?`. In order to get the **output** you'll need to explicitly keep it around - e.g.  with:

```
MYVAR=`pwd`
echo $MYVAR
```

Answer (score 1):

Use $? inorder to get the status of the last executed command. Its value will be zero if the last executed command was  successful else non zero.

Answer (score 1):

The internal variable `$?` holds the return value of the last executed command or program. Example: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/complexfunct.html#MAX.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to run one command first, you can also try using pipes | to connect commands.  I am constantly piping long directory listings over to more, so I can page through the results, with

```
 ls -al | more
```

so if you want to use the results of running pwd as input to another program, you can try something like piping the results of pwd over to more with

```
  pwd|more
```